# PHP, HTML multiple chexbox valuesc

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have got the php, html code.
And I want to post the multiple checkbox values, but this does not work dunno why, I can print count or array, it prints(0), does not matter
the array values is always empty

```
<form action = 'main.php?w=creatNewTemplate2' method = 'post'>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'templateName' maxlength = '30'/><br />
    <input type= 'checkbox' name= 'exercises[]' value='A' />A<br />
    <input type= 'checkbox' name= 'exercises[]' value='B' />B<br />
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Sukurti'/>
</form>

if($w == "creatNewTemplate2")
{
    $d = $_POST['exercises']; 
    $ddd = count($d);
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you print `$d`?

Comment: what exatcly is $w?

Comment: It's `$_GET["w"]`, not `$w`.

Comment: Print $ddd. May be a stupid question, but did you actually select any value? Non-checked will not appear at all. Could you post `print_r($_POST)` for us?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work for you:

```
if($w == "creatNewTemplate2")
{
    $d = $_POST['exercises']; 
    $ddd = count($d);

    for ($x = 0; $x < $ddd; $x++) {
        echo $_POST['exercises'][$x].'<br>';
    }
}
```

If you use same name you need to loop them

Comment: They should show in `print_r($_POST)`, I understand they don't.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek i agree! Also `print_r($_POST);` would be useful

Answer (score 0):

This should be work
Or you can change the two checkbox to select multiple

```html
<form action="main.php?w=creatNewTemplate2" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="templateName" maxlength="30"/><br/>
    <select multiple name="exercices[]">
       <option>A</option>
       <option>B</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Sukurti"/>
</form>
```

```
<?php

if($_GET["w"] == "creatNewTemplate2")
{ 

  foreach ($_POST["exercises"] as $ex) {
    echo $ex . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless the question is not ill-formed, I believe this is not where the problem is. OP says they can print count, so they should be inside if already.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek Look at my new answer, i think you should use select with multiple choice

Comment: That is one way of doing it, but honestly either should work. I think the bug is elsewhere.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek i think we miss something, take a look

Comment: We will get nowhere unless the OP prints us the `print_r($_POST)` I think :/

Comment: OP is the one who need to take a look. .. There are no point to guess if OP has no respond on what we have so far. .. Maybe issue is with posting to other url `action = 'main.php?w=creatNewTemplate2'`